# Laravel 5.4: api password reset updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.4, php 5.6
try to `updateOrCreate` password reset token her is my attempt.

```
$passwordReset = ( new PasswordReset )->updateOrCreate(
                ['email' => $user->email],
                [
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'token' => str_random(60)
                ]
            );
```

create working fine if the user reset his password for the first time, but when update I got this `QueryException`

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: update `password_resets` set `token` =
>   8ALMd5schQR9KNQ5kIt89bwr5lu5mb5G1DpYLttkizN6Z5ZxCcyhYaBp0X97 where
>   `id` is null)

Comment: What is the primary key name in your table?

Comment: @pr1nc3 my primary key name `email`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that laravel pre-defines your primary key to be id.

You have 3 solutions:

1) Either you add an id column, autoincrement and make it your primary
   key

2) Simple use:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'email';
```

to re-define your primary key in your Model,

3) Lastly you put a where clause by yourself:

```
->where('email',$user->email)
```

Comment: Thanks for `'token' => str_random(60)` will make sure to do that. but my mistake was I am putting the `'token' => str_random(60)]` in checking key it should be the way opposite this worked find with my `$passwordReset = ( new PasswordReset )->updateOrCreate(
    ['email' => $user->email, 'token' => str_random(60)],
    [ 'email' => $user->email, ]
   );`